# Ignore/prune hidden directories with GNU find command

Tags: bash

When using the `find` command, why is it that the following will successfully ignore hidden directories (those starting with a period) while matching everything else:

`find . -not \( -type d -name ".?*" -prune \)`

but this will not match anything at all:

`find . -not \( -type d -name ".*" -prune \)`

The only difference is the question mark.  Shouldn't the latter command likewise detect and exclude directories beginning with a period?

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Comment: @tommie - does it? depends on whether it's being used interactively or as part of a script; in the latter case, it's arguably a legitimate software development question.

Comment: downvoted for irrelevance of title mention of "GNU find" in selected answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The latter command prunes everything because it prunes `.` - try these to see the difference:

```
$ ls -lad .*
.
..
.dotdir
$ ls -lad .?*
..
.dotdir
```

You see that in the second one, `.` isn't included because it is only one character long. The glob "`.?*`" includes only filenames that are at least two characters long (dot, plus any single character, non-optionally, plus any sequence of zero or more characters).

By the way, `find` is not a Bash command.

Comment: "find is not a Bash command" - good call, changed title to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

The latter command prunes `.` itself -- the directory you're running `find` against -- which is why it generates no results.